# MongoDb Spring boot ,User entity could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using MongoDb With my spring boot project here is my entity user

```
package com.logan.cricketbeting.entities;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String username;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", username=" + username + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }
    private String password;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


}
```

And here is User repository

```
package com.logan.cricketbeting.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.logan.cricketbeting.entities.User;
//this is the repositiory for users
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
    @Query
    public User findByUsername(String username);

}
```

And here is Userservice

```
package com.logan.cricketbeting.Service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.logan.cricketbeting.entities.User;

@Service
public interface UserService {
    User saveUser(User User);
    User updateUser(User User);
    void deleteUser(User User);
    User getUserByusername(String username);
    List<User> getAllUsers();


}
```

And user service Impl

```
package com.logan.cricketbeting.Service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.logan.cricketbeting.entities.User;
import com.logan.cricketbeting.repositories.UserRepository;



public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {


    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Override
    public User saveUser(User User) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userRepository.save(User);

    }

    @Override
    public User updateUser(User User) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(User User) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public User getUserByusername(String username) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



}
```

And this is my index controller

```
package com.logan.cricketbeting.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.logan.cricketbeting.Service.UserServiceImpl;
import com.logan.cricketbeting.entities.User;

@Controller

public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    private User user;

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userservice;

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login()
    {
        return "user/login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/home")
public String index() {
    return "user/home.html";
}
    @RequestMapping("/aboutus")
    public String aboutus()
    {
        return "user/about-us";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/faqs")
    public String faqs()
    {
        return "user/faqs";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/register")
    public String register()
    {
        return "user/register";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/contactus")
    public String contactus()
    {
        return "user/contact-us";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/extra-menu")
    public String extramenu()
    {
        return "extra-menu";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/register")
    @ResponseBody
    public String registers()
    {
        user.setUsername("logan");
        user.setPassword("password");
        userservice.saveUser(user);

        return "User registered";
    }
}
```

And this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.logan.cricketbeting</groupId>
    <artifactId>cricketbettingspring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>cricketbettingspring</name>
    <description>cricketbettingspring</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I am getting this error

> Description:
>
> Field user in com.logan.cricketbeting.controllers.IndexController
>   required a bean of type 'com.logan.cricketbeting.entities.User' that
>   could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.logan.cricketbeting.entities.User' in your configuration.

I have already created entity with @Document annotation but it is still giving me this error any idea how to solve it??

Comment: It should be @Entity annotation.

Comment: No ,I am not using JPA here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate your user entity with

> @Component

,all you need is to make spring ApplicationContext find it. Like

```
@Component
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String username;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", username=" + username + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }
    private String password;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do, is to inject `User` in `IndexController`:

```
@Autowired
private User user;
```

User is not a bean managed by Spring IoC and therefore you're getting this error:

```
Field user in com.logan.cricketbeting.controllers.IndexController required a bean of type 'com.logan.cricketbeting.entities.User' that could not be found.
```

Solution:

Just instantiate your `User` in `registers()` method and anywhere where you need it:

```
@RequestMapping("/register")
@ResponseBody
public String registers() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername("logan");
    user.setPassword("password");
    userservice.saveUser(user);

    return "User registered";
}
```

Comment: @LOGAN Yes it is. Instances that need to be injected across the application context should be managed by IoC. In this case, User is a short lived instance that get's persisted and "thrown away".

Comment: so can I use @Component as suggested by someone in the answer??

Comment: @LOGAN I wouldn't do that. In matter of fact, why would you do that? I would have to sit back and think about vastness of consequences caused by a singleton bean that gets mutated upon each request.